# how to open phone dialler in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, openurl

I found solution that I need to add some code in `info.plist`. I did it like below:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>tel</string>
</array>
```

still no help.
 I get this error:

> "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tel://4806501708" - error: "This
>   app is not allowed to query for scheme tel"

my code for opening dialler:

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:lblVenPhoneValue.text];
if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

What do I need to do?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",@"digits"]]]; try this , without "//"

Comment: NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@number];   
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]]; check this too if above not work

Comment: no luck. still getting : "This app is not allowed to query for scheme telprompt"

Comment: is my info.plist correct? here it is

Comment: telprompt try this in info.plist

Comment: are you testing this on device ? , because this will not work on simulator . And device should have sim card too .

Comment: <dict>
 <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
 <string>en</string>
 <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
 <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
 <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
 <string>6.0</string>
 <key>CFBundleName</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
 <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
 <string>????</string>
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>1</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>tel</string>
        <string>telprompt</string>
    </array>
    
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: I forgot to mention that i use simulator. Maybe thats the reason of failure. I should check on device.

Comment: everything seems ok , You should test on device (with sim card)

Answer (score 14):

Are you testing this on device ? , because this will not work on simulator . And device should have sim card too .

After confirming above try following

In info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>tel</string>
<string>telprompt</string>
</array>
```

Where want to open phone dialler

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",@"digits"]]];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",@"digits"]]];
```

Comment: without adding **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** also it works fine

Answer (score 1):

just remove "//" from @"tel://" it should work

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel:" stringByAppendingString:lblVenPhoneValue.text];
if ([UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]]) {
        [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

For more better checks you can use

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:phoneNumber]]])
{
  CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
  CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
  NSString *_code = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
  if(_code)
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneNumber]];
  }
  else
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"no_sim" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
  }
}
else
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"alert" message:@"alert_device_not_support" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i use simulator. Maybe thats the reason of failure. I should check on device.

Comment: ohh. That should be the reason, then you should add check/alert for such conditions

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 4.0 use this(Make sure you are not on the simulator)

```
        let cleanPhoneNumber = phone.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
        let urlString:String = "tel://\(cleanPhoneNumber)"

        if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in the simulator, but it works fine in iPhone device.

**private func makeCall(number:String){**
        let number = "9876543210"

```
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```